# Write in a read-only file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, readonly, readonly-attribute

I am trying to open a read only file, read from it and write in in another read-only file but I get the following error `TypeError: excepted str, bytes or Os.Pathlike object, not NoneType`
My code goes like :
`copy_file=file`

`with open(os.chmod( file, stat.S_IREAD), ‘r’) as read_obj, open(os.chmod(copy_file, stat.S_IWRITE), ‘w’) as write_obj:`

`....`

Comment: You're trying to open output of `os.chmod`, not the actual file

Comment: When I try to open the file directly I get ```PermissionError :  Permission denied: file``` so that's why I'm using os.chmod

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve and if that is the best way, however, the exception you are getting:

```
TypeError: excepted str, bytes or Os.Pathlike object, not NoneType
```

is because you are trying to `open` output of `os.chmod`, which has no return value, if you want to `chmod` a file to be able to write to it and then make it read-only again, you can do something like this:

```py
import os
import stat

read_only_file = "1.txt"
read_write_file = "2.txt"

def make_read_only(filename: str) -> None:
    os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IREAD)

def make_read_write(filename: str) -> None:
    os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IWRITE)

# Read read only file
with open(read_only_file) as f:
    data = f.read()

make_read_write(read_write_file)
with open(read_write_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
make_read_only(read_write_file)
```

Bear in mind that this snippet will allow racing the file writeability, as there is a small period in which the file is writeable (race condition) - impact of this "feature" depends on your use case.

Comment: `def delete_line_by_string(original_file, line_to_delete)`
`is_skipped = False`
`copy_file= original_file`
`with open(os.chmod( file, stat.S_IREAD), ‘r’) as read_obj, open(os.chmod(copy_file, stat.S_IWRITE), ‘w’) as write_obj:`
 `for line in read_obj:`
  `line_to_match= line`
   `if line[-1] == '\n':`
    `line_to_match= line [:-1]`
      `if( line_to_delete in line_to_match) == False:`
        `write_obj.write(line)`
         `else:`
           `is_skipped= True`
`if is_skipped:`
 `os.remove(original_file)`
 `os.rename(copy_file, original_file)`
`else:`
 `os.remove(copy_file)`

Comment: Thanks what I actually wanted to do is delete a line according to a string, so if a string is found in the line of this file it should be deleted/removed. But the file is a read only so I either get `Permission denied` or `TypeError: ...,not Nonetype` .In my case my code looks like written above